# Output a server generated json object in jade without json parse

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, pug

I have a JSON object that does not conform to JSON standards, and I cannot change the structure of the object to make it adhere to JSON standards.

I need to make this object render in the middle of a javascript block in a Jade template. The object is actually a configuration object that is going in a function block in the template.

Here is the object.

```
{
  services: [],
  version: "1438276796258",
  country: "default",
  role: "User",
  Zack_Init: function () {

  },
  Zack_Global: function (event) {

  },
  Zack_PostRender: function () {

  }, 
  renderers: ['Renderer', 'NONE']
}
```

**UPDATE**
Here is how I am getting that object from a JS file.

```
function readJSFile(url, filename, callback) {
  fs.readFile(url, "utf-8", function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
      return;
    }
    try {
      callback(filename, data);
    } catch (exception) {
      callback(exception);
    }
  });
}
```

When JSON.stringify processes the object it drops the three functions in the conversion process.

I am adding a plunker to show the progress of the current solution.   Which outputs the below.  The only thing left is to remove the formatting characters.

```
{"services":[],"version":"1438276796258","country":"default","role":"User","Zack_Init":function () {\n\n },"Zack_Global":function (event) {\n\n },"Zack_PostRender":function () {\n\n },"renderers":["Renderer","NONE"]}
```

```js
function convertToString(obj) {
  return JSON.stringify(obj, function(k, v) {
    return (typeof v === 'function' ? ['@@beginFunction@@', v.toString(), '@@endFunction@@'].join('') : v);
  }).replace(/"@@beginFunction@@|@@endFunction@@"/g, '');
}

obj = {
  services: [],
  version: "1438276796258",
  country: "default",
  role: "User",
  Zack_Init: function() {

  },
  Zack_Global: function(event) {

  },
  Zack_PostRender: function() {

  },
  renderers: ['Renderer', 'NONE']
};

$('#test').text(convertToString(obj));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: What is the specific issue? What have you tried that didn't work? Are you just display a string?

Comment: Updated to give the actual issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to remove new line characters safely, 'comments' should be removed first:

```js
function convertToString(obj) {
  return JSON.stringify(obj, function(k, v) {
    return (
      typeof v !== 'function' ? 
        v :
        v.toString().replace(/\/\/.*?$/mg, '')        // removes single line comments
                    .replace(/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//g, '') // removes multi-line comments
                    .replace(/[\r\n]/g, '')           // removes new line
    );
  }, 2).replace(/"(function.+)",?$/gm, '$1');         // removes quotes around functions
}

obj = {
  services: [],
  version: "1438276796258",
  country: "default",
  role: "User",
  Zack_Init: function() {
    // comment
    var a = 1;// comment //
    if(a === /*comment */ 3) {//comment
      /* comment
      comment*/
    }
    /*end*/
  },
  Zack_Global: function(event) {
  },
  Zack_PostRender: function() {
  },
  renderers: ['Renderer', 'NONE']
};

$('#result').text(convertToString(obj));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: this got me most of the way there, was a small part I needed to take care of but this was the base for the solutions.   Thank you.

Comment: for those who are curious, here are the two things I had to change: `.replace(/[\r\n\t]/g, '')`
`.replace(/\u007d$/, '},')`

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding your request correctly (that you want to take the contents of a file that's loaded externally and then load it in a `<script>` block), I think the solutions that have been explored so far are largely over-engineered.

Here's what I have:

```
// index.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  readJSFile('./whacky_obj.js', 'whacky_json_obj.js', render); // used .js because OP implies that as the file source in the extraction method
  function render(fname, obj) {
    res.render('index', { jsObj: obj });
  }
});

// OP's readJSFile method
function readJSFile(url, filename, callback) {
  fs.readFile(url, "utf-8", function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
      return;
    }
    try {
      callback(filename, data);
    } catch (exception) {
      callback(exception);
    }
  });
}

module.exports = router;
```

And then in your Jade file:

```
block content
  h1= title
  script!= jsObj
```

You can see the output from the `jsObj` variable if you swap `script` for `pre`, but `script` will do what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Is the configuration object something you need to select or modify dynamically? Could you use an include? If not, then unescaped buffer code (http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/) seems like the way to go with the string passed back by readFile.

---

Stringify solution:

EDIT: better solution than my original proposal:

```
function funcyStringify(obj) {
    var funcMap = {};
    var sections = JSON.stringify(obj, function(k, v) {
        if (typeof v === 'function') {
            funcMap[k] = v;
            return ['@@function@@', k, '@@function@@'].join('');
        }
        return v;
    }).split(/"?@@function@@"?/g);
    for (var i = 1; i < sections.length-1; i+=2) {
        sections[i] = funcMap[sections[i]];
    }
    return sections.join('');
}
```

It'll need a bit more work if you need to have the same property name in nested objects referring to different functions.

---

Originally wrote:

Not familiar enough with Jade to type this out in it, but with EJS, you could do something like this:

```
<script>
var configObject = {
<% for (var key in configObject) {
     if (configObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) { %>
       <%- key %>:
       <% if (typeof configObject[key] === 'function') { %>
           <%- configObject[key].toString() %>
       <% } else { %>
           <%- JSON.stringify(configObject[key]) %>
       <% } %>
<% } } %>
};
</script>
```

Gets more complicated if you have functions below the top level.

Comment: the better solution is getting me pretty close however the `.toString()` method is adding formatting characters like `\n` and `\t`.  How can I remove those as well?

Comment: Edited to take out \n and \t. Also changed the replacement string from empty string to single space, just in case. It'll need more modifications if you use double quotes in your functions or if you use escape characters (you can fiddle around with the replacement regex -- might need multiple replace calls).

Comment: having it remove the characters does work, but I found that it interferes with comments that are in the code `//` then comments out the entire javascript block.   I am adding a bounty to this.  Hope we can get this last part figured out and I will throw the bounty your way.  Thanks :)

Comment: @zmanc, edited; hopefully it works for you :) -- one limitation is that currently doesn't handle nested objects with the same property name referring to different functions.